# Unable to Save IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
if (settings.Contains("myDetailsObject"))
    {
        settings["myDetailsObject"] = myDetails;
    }
    else
    {
        settings.Add("myDetailsObject", myDetails);
    }
   settings.Save();
```

Tried doing the below, however it gave me error. those save values are in strings and is a custom object. tried even saving an integer instead and is still not working

```
Type 'SharedLibary.Object.MyDetailsObject' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the attribute [DataMember] on all properties that you want to serialize in your MyDetailsObject class.

Answer (score 1):

Mark class with `[DataContractAttribute]` attribute and all members that you want to serialize with `[DataMemberAttribute]`. Note, that marked properties must be `public`.

Also, don't forget to add reference to System.Runtime.Serialization